# SessionFactory and interfaces implementations beans cannot be created

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

When trying to run my app, spring throws a few error messages due to not being able to create beans.

1. org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'pl.coderstrust.dao.FooDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
2. Error creating bean with name 'fooServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'.

```
public interface FooService {
      public void add(Foo body);
    }


    @Service
    public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

      @Autowired
      FooDao dao;

      @Transactional
      @Override
      public void add(Foo body) {
        dao.add(body);
      }
    }

public interface FooDao {
  void  add(Foo body);
}

@Repository
public class FooDaoImpl implements FooDao{

  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Override
  public void add(Foo body) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(body);
  }
}
```

As a result, my controller bean could not be created as well:
Error creating bean with name 'fooController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'impl'

I have no .xml file with beans, only annotations. When running the app, all the configs are being read from java class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScans(value = {
    @ComponentScan("pl.coderstrust.hibernate"),
    @ComponentScan("pl.coderstrust.serv"),
    @ComponentScan("pl.coderstrust.dao"),
})
public class AppConfig {

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Bean
  public DataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
    props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
    props.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));

    factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
    factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(Invoice.class);
    return factoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }
}
```

My sessionFactory bean is not being created as well. BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in pl.coderstrust.hibernate.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed;
I went through a few answers on stackoverflow, as well as some tutorials, some of them say the annotations should be added to interfaces not its implementations. I've tried all the possible options and added all the annotations according to recommendations. 
Maybe someone had the same issue, what needs to be changed?

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "pl.coderstrust")
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    InvoiceServiceImpl service = context.getBean(InvoiceServiceImpl.class);

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);

    LocalDate expectedDate = LocalDate.now();
    Counterparty expectedCounterparty
        = CounterpartyBuilder.builder().withCompanyName("LPD").build();
    int expectedNumberOfItem = 1;
    String expectedDescription = "test";
    BigDecimal expectedAmount = BigDecimal.TEN;
    BigDecimal expectedVatAmount = BigDecimal.ONE;
    Vat expectedVat = Vat.VAT_23;
    InvoiceBody invoiceBody = new InvoiceBody(expectedDate, expectedCounterparty, Arrays.asList(
        new InvoiceItem(expectedDescription, expectedNumberOfItem, expectedAmount,
            expectedVatAmount, expectedVat)));
    service.add(invoiceBody);

  }
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the AppConfig class?

Comment: @Plog    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

Comment: Out of interest what are you actually trying to do ? Just save a JPA entity ?

If so just add the spring data jpa starter, extend the CrudRepository interface and call save on the entity. No need to worry about session factories etc,

Comment: Can you show your main Spring Boot class?

Comment: @Plog added to the question. I tried to test it by saving one invoice.

Comment: @PaulNUK I am trying to test hibernate impl my saving one entity.

Comment: removing @ComponentScans(value = {
    @ComponentScan("pl.coderstrust.hibernate"),
    @ComponentScan("pl.coderstrust.serv"),
    @ComponentScan("pl.coderstrust.dao"),
})
helped for implementation beans, however, sessionFactory bean still cannot be created :(

Comment: Why on earth are you creating an application context yourself? Spring Boot already does that, remove that code. Also `@EnableTransactionManagement` isn't needed that is automatically enabled by Spring Boot. You are trying very hard not to use the frameworks you have on your class path.

Comment: I suggest you just follow a simple Spring Data JPA/Spring Boot tutorial

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/